# apache is not responding from the outside (firewall/iptables problem)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

Have `CentOS` installed with `httpd`. Can connect with `lynx` both to `http://localhost` and to `http://10.20.30.40` (the real IP) from *inside* the machine. Can't connect from *outside*. Here is an excerpt from the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

<VirtualHost 10.20.30.40:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost1
    ErrorLog logs/vhost1-error_log
    CustomLog logs/vhost1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to connect from the machine that resides on the same subnet (as far as I know about it).

Nothing suspicious in the log files. Any advises please?

**Update**: while running `iptables -L` I've got the following line (maybe it's related): `REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`.

**Update N2**: `iptables -vnL` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:67
1576K 1643M RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 354K packets, 58M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  922  823K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   19  1412 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 159K   28M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353
 2869  640K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631
1239K 1589M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    8  1064 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
 175K   25M REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: You need to give WAY more information.

Comment: @Phil: kindly advise which information would you like to get and I'll happily provide it.

Comment: @BreakFreak: "REJECT all" is probably the cause!

Comment: @Cez: can you please tell which is the best way to remove the line (this is not a production machine)? Also, can you please post it as an answer, so I'll "accept" it if it helps?

Comment: @BreakFreak: have added an answer

Comment: @BreakFreak: port 80 isn't open in your config

Comment: @BreakFreak, Cez: even on a test system a default policy of REJECT or DROP should be the default - you need to add an entry to allow port 80 as per Cez's answer - NOT the comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this to see if it helps:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
```

If you use the following beforehand then you can easily revert back:

```
/sbin/iptables-save > /tmp/fw
```

If you want to completely turn off iptables (although better to configure it appropriately) then use:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig iptables off
```

Otherwise, make the rule persist save it to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

### On CentOS 7 or above

On CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 you would probably use the `firewall-cmd` to allow HTTP traffic.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Just switched off the firewall as advised above and it worked. Now the point is how to switch it forever.

Comment: Note: with `-A INPUT` the new rule comes after all other rules in the input chain. That means that the new rule may come after a general REJECT rule, making it useless. To add the new rule at the top, use `-I INPUT` instead

Answer (score 1):

This is often indicative of a firewall problem, either on your local system or on your network.  What does your local `iptables` firewall look like?

```
# iptables -vnL
```

You can temporarily disable the local firewall by running:

```
# /sbin/service iptables stop
```

If things work after this, it was definitely a firewall problem and you'll need to sort that out.

If you don't have a local firewall, is there one elsewhere on your network?

Comment: Updated the post with `iptables -vnL` output.

Comment: Yep, stopping the iptables makes the job! Now the question is how to remove the firewall. No need in it - this is a pure dev machine.

Comment: `rm /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'd say that firewall rule probably isn't helping things (although it depends what else is in the firewall ruleset).  It could also (in theory) be a problem with the outgoing firewall on the machine you're connecting from, or a proxy config problem, or the phase of the moon.

A complete firewall ruleset and some detailed network troubleshooting results would go a long way to narrowing down the problem.