# Oracle Linux 7: web server not reachable

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, oracle-linux

Here's my setup.  I have a vm running with Oracle Linux 7 installed.  I started apache with `service httpd start` and it started without issue.  I've created an `index.html` file in both `/var/www/html` and `/var/www`.  I'm able to reach the VM from my host machine using `ping` or `ssh`, but when I open a web browser and navigate to the IP address, the server doesn't respond.

I checked `netstat -plent` and it shows that port 80 is listening:

```
# netstat -plent
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          121584     36432/httpd
```

I've [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936606/apache-and-httpd-running-but-i-cant-see-my-website) at [several](https://serverfault.com/questions/289025/apache-is-not-responding-from-the-outside-firewall-iptables-problem) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43992/problems-setting-up-web-server-in-centos) that suggest iptables may be the issue, but none of those solutions helped.  What else might be causing the problem?

Comment: Just to be sure, your client is trying to access the service over ipv6 right?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I navigate to `192.168.80.130` in the browser

Comment: So what does your firewall look like?

Comment: @MichaelHampton http://pastebin.com/LhPdqnkJ. If that's not what you're looking for let me know.  I'm a developer so I don't have a ton of experience with sysadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to open the port in the firewall.

For instance.

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=http
```

Remember to [make it permanent](http://serverfault.com/a/622207/126632) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're listening only on IPv6, going by that netstat output.

You need to either access the website only using IPv6, or create another listener directive in apache to listen on 0.0.0.0:80.  In httpd.conf:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

You can, of course, listen only on the IP address you want to serve traffic on.

This advice isn't right if you have support for dual-stack sockets in Linux, though.  You might only need to check that dual-stack listening is turned on.  Using procfs, check this file:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only
```

If it is not 0, you need to change it in your configuration to 0, or listen on IPv4 explicitly.

Also, check your firewall rules; if you're rejecting the traffic on ipv4 or ipv6, that would explain it.  Check here:

```
iptables -t filter -nvL INPUT
ip6tables -t filter -nvL INPUT
```

If the default policy is not ACCEPT and you don't have a rule allowing HTTP traffic in, or if you have rules blocking it, that would explain.

Comment: That's normal for a dual stack socket.

Comment: no change. modified `httpd.conf` and restarted `httpd` but the page is still not reachable

Comment: `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` is 0